# Best way to send e-mail programmatically from docker container (Spring Boot app) hosted Amazon AWS ECS Cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, jakarta-mail, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I was wondering if anyone could advise the "best" (I know that's subjective, but meaning "best" as in least amount of work/steps) to trigger sending an E-mail from Amazon AWS. The Message body with contain dynamic variables/data from my App (Spring boot) so I will have to wire that in somehow, and it should be triggered from within my Application whenever it finishes processing some data, since my app reads .CSV data.

1. I cannot use JavaMail/Jakarta to send e-mail from within app as all Containers I have have blocked ports
2. Preferably using some type of AWS service since I'm already hosting this app on AWS ECS cluster

I would like to do it programmatically:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS provides [Amazon Simple Email Service (SES)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/Welcome.html)  which is:

> is an email platform that provides an **easy**, cost-effective way for you to send and receive email using your own email addresses and domains.

To use that, you would add SES permissions to your [ECS tasks role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html). This way, you don't need to hard-code any AWS credentials into your application, as they will be automatically obtained by AWS SDK when interacting with SES.

AWS also provides [AWS SDK for java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html). Using the SDK you can send emails using SES as shown in the example [Send an email using the AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-java.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send an email from a Spring Boot app, then use the Simple Email Service Java V2 API. There is [an AWS Java V2 tutorial](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app) that shows how to build a Spring BOOT app that uses various AWS Services to analyze photos located in an Amazon S3 bucket. This app uses the SES Java V2 API to send a report that contains the details of the Amazon Rekognition service that analyzes the photos.